# can you major in choral works as an instrumentation or is it just voice?

Tags: voice, education, choral

Sorry for, like, the dumb question, but **do people actively try to join choral ensembles** (and thus major in the choir as an instrumentation), or **do they just go into voice for their majors?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people study music they can pick a concentration: voice, a instrument, composition, and conducting are all quite common. A person can focus graduate studies in choral conducting, but it is not possible to concentrate on choirs as an instrument.

People who study voice are often required to sing in choirs, and this is where their choir experience comes from.